# Modifying other core editor panels besides Featured Image in the block editor

Tags: block-editor

The following code allows the addition of elements above/below the default content of the Featured Image panel in the Gutenberg editor.

```jsx
    const { createElement, Fragment } = wp.element;
    const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
    function wrapPostFeaturedImage(OriginalComponent) {
      return function(props) {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            Prepend above
            <OriginalComponent {...props} />
            Append below
          </Fragment>
        );
      };
    }
    addFilter(
      'editor.PostFeaturedImage',
      'my-plugin/wrap-post-featured-image',
      wrapPostFeaturedImage
    );
```

[image]

Is anything like this available for the other core panels?

- Categories
- Tags
- Excerpt

I'm not finding any clarity in the documentation (i.e. no obvious filter hooks for editor.Categories, editor.Tags, or editor.Excerpt). Just to be clear, I want to modify *existing* panels with additional content/controls.